# RSpec/Capybara Issue with Select Dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec

At the moment I am trying to implement testing onto my already existing Signup page. There are a variety of required areas to fill out, two of them being a drop down for area location. The first is to select your country and then a subregion selector will appear for that country with the various states/regions to choose from. This seems to cause an issue I believe with RSpec, though unsure why. Here is my code below:

```
#Signup View
....
<p>
<%= f.label :country, "Country *", class: "input_title" %><br />
<%= f.country_select :country, {priority: %w(US CA), prompt: 'Please select a country'} %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :state, "Region/State *", class: "input_title"  %><br />
<%= render partial: '/users/subregion_select', locals: {parent_region: f.object.country} %>
</p>
....

#Partial for State Selection
<div id="user_state_wrapper">
  <% parent_region ||= params[:parent_region] %> <% unless parent_region.nil? %>
  <% country = Carmen::Country.coded(parent_region) %> 
  <% end %>

  <% if country.nil? %>
    Please select a country above
  <% elsif country.subregions? %>
    <%= subregion_select(:user, :state, parent_region) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= text_field(:user, :state) %>
  <% end %>
</div>

#_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Users can signup" do
  scenario "with valid attributes" do
    visit "/"
    click_link "Signup"

    fill_in "Username *", with: "TestUser"
    fill_in "First Name *", with: "Joe"
    fill_in "Last Name *", with: "Dayvie"
    fill_in "Email *", with: "joe@dayvie.com"
    fill_in "Confirm Email *", with: "joe@dayvie.com"
    select "United States", from: "Country *", match: :first
    select "Nevada", from: "Region/State *"
    fill_in "City *", with: "Las Vegas"
    fill_in "Create Password *", with: "password"
    fill_in "Confirm Password *", with: "password"

    click_button "Signup"
  end
end

#Failure from Test
Failure/Error: select "Nevada", from: "Region/State *"
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find select box "Region/State *"
```

I am assuming this occurs because the selection box appears; however, this should work since it does select a country correctly? If I have anything wrong, or need more code, please let me know and I can do so. I appreciate any input, thank you!

Comment: Might have something to do the the slash being an escape character.  Just as an experiment, try changing "Region/State" to "RegionState" in both the test and the view, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for that idea but that was not the issue - I still received `Unable to find select box "Region *"`

Comment: Have you used the browser to examine the generated html to verify the element exists with that name?

Comment: Yes, this is a signin page that has been used many times and only now going back to implement testing.

Comment: Well, you could post the relevant HTML and see if anyone can spot anything.

Comment: I posted the portion of the form which is relevant to this question? Unless there is another portion that would be helpful I am unaware of? All the other portions go through correctly, including the country. It is just the :state which seems to be an issue.

Comment: The select box itself is in the partial.  Lets see that?  Or the HTML that got generated (Use inspect element in the browser)

Comment: I just added the code for the partial within the main question. Very odd that when I do check the page source, even when the drop down box is there, the code does not show it? All I see is the following: `<label class="input_title" for="user_Region/State *">Region/state *</label><br />
      <div id="user_state_wrapper">
  
  Please select a country above
</div>`

Comment: If it's on the screen, then it has to be in the html :-).  Did you expand the right section(s) when you inspected the html in the browser?  You're looking for the select box, not the label.  My hunch is that the id on the select box does not match the label (and thus not the id you are giving to Capybara).  Note how the HTML generated for the `country` select has a `label_for` that matches the ID of the select?  And probably not the case for `subregion`?  You need to give Capybara the ID of the select box.  You can also dump the html during the test by `puts page.body`

Answer (score 0):

If appearance of sub region is done by javascript, then please use js: true.

```
scenario "with valid attributes", js: true do

end
```

Comment: When I make that addition, I seem to receive the following failure for the test: `Failure/Error: visit /
     LoadError:
       Capybara's selenium driver is unable to load selenium-webdriver, please install the gem and add gem selenium-webdriver to your Gemfile if you are using bundler.` - I removed the quotes from the visit "/", but otherwise, that is an issue I've never seen. Obviously I could install the gem, but is this type of failure normal?

Comment: Please install gem selenium-webdriver, and then give it a try.

Comment: Now it is telling me it cannot find the click_link Signup, which it was doing perfectly fine before...not too sure if installing this gem was the right route to go?

Comment: Now it just threw up a completely different failure:   1) Users can signup with valid attributes
     Failure/Error: click_link "Signup"
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError:
       Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: ``expect(page).to have_selector('#blah', visible: true)`` or you can use capybara#find so that it can wait until the element is available.